# Adding to a random number

Tags: java

I have used the Random class to generate a random number and the number shows up, but when I try to add that generated random number with 10 it just get concatenated i.e if the random number is 20 it will show as 2010

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class MainClass{
    static int x = 50;
    static  int y = 10;

    public class InnerClass {    
        double myDouble = x;

        void show() {
            System.out.println(myDouble + 5);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random rand = new Random();
        MainClass obj1 = new MainClass();
        MainClass.InnerClass obj2 = obj1.new InnerClass();

        int int_random = rand.nextInt(x);

        System.out.println(int_random + " :" + " This is the Random Number and its plus 10 is "+ int_random + y);

        // obj2.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: add parentheses around `(int_random + y)`.

Comment: `+` is left associative in Java, meaning `"... is " + int_random + y` is the same as `("... is " + int_random) + y`

Comment: I've removed the `random` tag, you'd have the same issue with printing fixed values the way you've done it.  Randomness has nothing to do with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator in Java can do two very different things: adding two numbers, and concatenating two strings. If you "add" a number to a string, the number is first converted into a string, and then the two strings are concatenated.

The other piece of the puzzle is that `+` is applied left to right (it's *left-associative*). So if you write `a + b + c`, that means `(a + b) + c` and not `a + (b + c)`. So if either `a` is a string and `b` and `c` are integers, `(a + b)` will be a string, and `c` is converted to a string before being added to it.

The solution is to force the order of evaluation using parentheses: write `a + (b + c)` explicitly, or in your case:

```
    System.out.println(int_random + " :" + " This is the Random Number and its plus 10 is "+ (int_random + y));
```

Comment: `So if you write a + b + c, that means (a + b) + c` - This is wrong. `int x = 5, y = 10, z = 15;
  System.out.println("Hello" + x + y + z);` will print `Hello51015
` . As per your explanation, it would have printed `Hello1515`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash As per his explanation, you would add "Hello" and x first, not x and y like you imply with a result Hello1515. His explanation is correct

Comment: I've got it. Thank you. As per his explanation, `a` is `Hello` in my expression and therefore it will be evaluated as `("Hello" + 5) + 10` and finally, `"Hello510" + 15` which will be evaluated to `Hello51015`.